# Consistency of bash redirection to the same file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to redirect stdout and stderr of some command to files passed as parameters to my script. The parameters are optional and by default they are `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` accordingly.

That's why I redirect in the following way `some-command 1>$myStdout 2>$myStderr`. Since I don't know beforehand whether `myStdout` and `myStderr` are the same, I can't use such `2>&1` kind of form of redirection.

And here comes the problem. If `myStdout` and `myStderr` point to the same file I can loose some output. Consider following script

```
>&2 echo "err" &
echo "out"
```

If I run it like `test.sh 1>log 2>&1` then I see both lines in log file, but If I run it like `test.sh 1>log 2>log` then I see only `err`.

Here is the first question: why is that happening? How bash handles concurrent writes in the above examples?

And how can I fix it? I understand that I can check if files the same

```
if [[ $myStdout and $myStderr are the same ]]; then
  redirect using 1>$myStdout 2>&1
else
  redirect using 1>$myStdout 2>$myStderr
fi
```

But this way is ugly. I have to somehow check that files are the same (and deal with symbolic links resolving) and I have to duplicate the command which rather large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the descriptors separately, they're totally independent streams. If they're pointing to the same file, they'll each keep track of the file offset independently. So the first time you write to one stream it will write to the beginning of the file, and the first time you write to the other it will also write to the beginning of the file, overwriting what the previous write did. This will keep happening, with writes to each stream overwriting the other.

What you can do is first empty each file, then open them both in append mode:

```
> $myStdout
> $myStderr
redirect 1>> $myStdout 2>> $myStderr
```

By appending, each write will first seek to the end of the file, so it will go after whatever the previous write did, rather than overwriting it.

However, there may be another issue. If the program uses stdio, it buffers `stdout` by default, but not `stderr`. So unless the program flushes the `stdout` buffer before printing error messages, they're likely to get interspersed in random places in the output, not neatly on their own lines.

Comment: Good answer! Thank you for mentioning stdout buffering. Is it possible to somehow keep all redirection details in a variable, so I can switch it depending on whether files are the same?

Comment: Not any easy way that I can think of. The buffering issues will occur whether you use the same stream or different streams, because it occurs at the stdio level.

Answer (score 1):

Let's explain :

- `test.sh 1>log 2>&1` : redirects STDERR to STDOUT and then all STDOUT to `log`
- `test.sh 1>log 2>log` : redirects STDERR to `log` and STDOUT to `log`

The difference is that on the first example, shell holds only one file handler to `log` whereas it opens 2 file handlers on the 2nd example.

What you should do is `truncate` your output files before starting the execution and then use append redirect `>>` instead of the normal `>`
 which truncate the output file when it is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using one overwrite and one append mode redirection:

```
bash test.sh >>"$myStdout" 2>"$myStderr"
```

If you just use `>` and same file in both stdout and stderr then shell truncates your file twice once for stderr redirection and second time for stdout redirection thus only leaving one output in that file.

Comment: With this, normal output will be appended nicely, but errors will go back and overwrite the normal output, because they're not being appended.

Comment: Actually in my testing I am getting both stdout and stderr with this approach.

Comment: Have you disabled buffering of stdout?

Comment: Yes I used `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 bash test.sh >>out 2>out` to test this on bash 4.3.33